# A visible window cannot be recognized in pywinauto

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

While writing scripts, I am attempting to look at some items in the Device Manager. The only issue is that pywinauto cannot see the device manager. Below is what I get when looking for "Device Manager":

```
Could not find 'Device Manager' in 'dict_keys(['', 'Pane', 'Taskbar', 'Pane0', 'Pane1', 'Pane2', 'TaskbarPane', 
'Pane3', 'NetBannerPane', 'Pane4', 'NetBanner', 'ListBox', 'Program ManagerPane', 'Program Manager', 'Pane5'])'
```

I have attempted to print_control_identifiers() for all of the items listed here however, none of them are the device manager. Looking within Inspect.exe, I can clearly see that there is a window with the title of "Device Manager".

[image: Inspect.exe screenshot]

I've even tried to access it via:

```
 dlg=Desktop(background='uia')
 dlg.window(class_name="MMCMainFrame").print_control_identifiers()
```

However, it also provides an error stating that it's an invalid name for the element and it cannot be found. Has anyone else ever attempted to use pywinauto to look at the Device Manager? Or had an issue being unable to find an element

Answer (score 1):

try using this code:

```
dlg = Desktop(background="uia")
dlg.window(title="Device Manager").print_control_identifiers()
```

Use title or title_re instead of class_name. dlg.window(title="Device Manger") returns device manager window handler if window is opened already.
[Heres find window documentation](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.findwindows.html)

Comment: What you commented is what I have tried. Pywinauto cannot find the device manager regardless of what control identifier is added (ie. title, class_name, etc). As stated above, _'Looking within Inspect.exe, I can clearly see that there is a window with the title of "Device Manager"'_ . If you were able to get this to work, then I'd would appreciate getting some additional information (pywinauto or python versions, etc.)

Comment: Well I tried it with Python 2.7 and pywinautio 0.6.8 Release it worked for me. Maybe it is the python version.. Ill try it later and update you on that.